# Keep communication open between server and client - Java

Tags: java, sockets, client, server, serversocket

How do you make a client which is able to send a server multiple messages at anytime, and therefore a server listening for a message all the time.

Right now I have wrote some code which only allows me to send a message once. I thought this was due to me closing the input/output streams and the sockets. So I have been playing around for a while now and I can't seem to do it!

Client:

```
public class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream os;

    public Client() {}

    public void connectToServer(String host, int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sendMessage();
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
        try {
            os = socket.getOutputStream();

            String string = "Anthony";
            byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            os.write(b);
            os.flush();

            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void STOP() {
        stopOutput();
        stopServer();
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopOutput() {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        String clientAddress = clientSocket.getInetAddress().toString()
            .substring(1);
        System.out.println("Connected to " + clientAddress);

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    data.add(inputLine);
                }

                if (data.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println(data.toString());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void STOP() {
        stopInput();
        stopConnection();
    }

    public void stopInput() {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopConnection() {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment on the client side, I send a message as soon as the socket is opened but after when I call the send function from another class it does not send...

How should I do this? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I am guessing client-server is the same as server-client, so if I know how to do one way I can easily switch it around... right?

Comment: read about  concept called **multi-threading**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns outs it was a simple error.

I as writing (sending-client) as an OutputStream however I was then reading (receiving-server) as BufferedReader! ha

So quick tip for anyone, make sure you receive messages the same way you send them!

Thanks for everyone who tried helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is accepting data all the time, so you just have to save the OutputStream of you Client somewhere and write data to it every now and then. But do not close it, because then you close the Client socket, too.

After you have done that, you would need to change something else, because now your call of `in.readLine()` blocks your server, because it waits for the client to send something. To prevent that, you could try to add sending a String like "close" to the server when you want to close your client, something like that:

```
public void STOP() {
    os.write("close".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    stopOutput();
    stopServer();
}
```

and change the code in your server to

```
try {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String inputLine;
    while (!(inputLine = in.readLine()).equals("close")) {
        data.add(inputLine);
    }

    if (data.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(data.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this, in client I moved:
    os = socket.getOutputStream();
which was in 'sendMessage()', to 'connectToServer()' underneath:
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
and then obviously took away the
    os.close();
in 'sendMessage()', however once I do this, the server did not even receive the first message I sent once the socket has been created.

And when you say every so often, do you mean like every 2 hours?
And why is this not working? :S

Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: I made the changes and I understand what you mean, but It does not work unless I close the OutputStream straight away. What am I doing wrong!?